# How to get missing in-tree kernel module?

Tags: drivers, kernel

I'm trying to install an in-tree kernel module, mgag200, that appears to be absent from the Ubuntu apt repositories.
The config for my kernel shows it wasn't set to build

```
$ grep MGAG200 /boot/config-$(uname -r)
# CONFIG_DRM_MGAG200 is not set
```

`modprobe` isn't finding it

```
$ modprobe -n mgag200
modprobe: FATAL: Module mgag200 not found in directory /lib/modules/4.8.0-42-generic
```

It doesn't turn up as builtin

```
$ grep mgag200 /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.builtin
```

Search for a package containing the file only turns up headers

```
$ apt-file search mgag200
linux-headers-4.8.0-22: /usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-22/drivers/gpu/drm/mgag200/Kconfig
linux-headers-4.8.0-22: /usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-22/drivers/gpu/drm/mgag200/Makefile
⋮
linux-headers-4.8.0-42: /usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-42/drivers/gpu/drm/mgag200/Kconfig
linux-headers-4.8.0-42: /usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-42/drivers/gpu/drm/mgag200/Makefile
```

I've uncommented all repositories in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` and synchronized the cache for all searches. I'm using a fully upgraded release

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.10
Release:        16.10
Codename:       yakkety
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Are modules like this supposed to be missing?
What's the regular approach for getting them?
Though I'm considering building it if necessary, I thought in-tree kernel modules would already be built and available.

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu! Thanks for taking the time to write a high quality question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The modules that are not enabled in `.config` are not built and are not "available".

There is a ton of in-tree modules that are not enabled in Ubuntu `.config`. The whole point of having a `.config` is not to compile each and every kernel module. Each distro maintainers choose which modules to include.

You need to build a custom kernel to get this module, or build it separately.

If you want to have a custom module that will survive kernel upgrades, you can make a DKMS package using the kernel source code. But some extra actions should be done to get it built if if is not enabled in `.config`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought distros typically packaged less needed in-tree modules apart in optional packages. If that doesn't exist, I'm thinking of creating a Debian package by adapting an existing package for another in-tree module. However, my search skills aren't very good. Do you know any good candidates?

Comment: If this is a separate module (`ko` file), you can create a DKMS deb package. It will survive kernel upgrades of your system. The problem with kernel module is that they have to be built for each kernel from source. DKMS does that automatically.

Comment: @Pilot6, so do you have a DKMS solution that enables some CONFIG_ and builds a missing module? It should be a common use case.

Comment: @Velkan I don't have anything special. It is not hard to build any module as a DKMS deb.

Comment: @Pilot6, the difference is that you usually include the source code into that deb. Yes, copy-pasting is easy, but automatically getting sources from the currently installed kernel is preferable.